# Packages not found in Java Spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am following a tutorial on how to run integration tests in Spring, but I have reached a bit of a bump. All my imports are saying the package does not exists. I tried switching from Gradle to Maven but it still did not work.

Here is what my terminal look like when I try to run the application:

```
    src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:6: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
                          ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:9: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                                                   ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:10: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
                                                   ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:11: error: package org.springframework.test.context does not exist
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
                                       ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:12: error: package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
                                              ^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Matchers
  location: package org.hamcrest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:14: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Matchers
  location: package org.hamcrest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:15: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
^
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class })
 ^
  symbol: class ContextConfiguration
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
@WebAppConfiguration
 ^
  symbol: class WebAppConfiguration
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
            ^
  symbol:   class WebApplicationContext
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
            ^
  symbol:   class MockMvc
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
         ^
  symbol: class SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class })
                                  ^
  symbol: class ApplicationConfig
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    @Autowired
     ^
  symbol:   class Autowired
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    @Before
     ^
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable MockMvcBuilders
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        ServletContext servletContext = wac.getServletContext();
        ^
  symbol:   class ServletContext
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        Assert.assertTrue(servletContext instanceof MockServletContext);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class MockServletContext
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
          .perform(get("/hello"))
                   ^
  symbol:   method get(String)
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
          .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                 ^
  symbol:   method print()
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
          .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                                    ^
  symbol:   method status()
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
          .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                     ^
  symbol:   method content()
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.manufacturer").value("Nissan"))
                     ^
  symbol:   method jsonPath(String)
  location: class CarTest
src/main/java/cars/CarTest.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("GT"));
                     ^
  symbol:   method jsonPath(String)
  location: class CarTest
```

As you can see, everything is not found, as a beginner this is driving me nuts. I know there is probably a small mistake I am making, but I would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Below is my integration test file:

```
    package cars;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CarTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenWac_whenServletContext_thenItProvidesGreetController() {
        ServletContext servletContext = wac.getServletContext();

        Assert.assertNotNull(servletContext);
        Assert.assertTrue(servletContext instanceof MockServletContext);
        Assert.assertNotNull(wac.getBean("carController"));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkHelloResponse() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
          .perform(get("/hello"))
          .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.manufacturer").value("Nissan"))
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("GT"));
    }
}
```

And finally the pom.xml, file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Which of the dependencies do you believe pulls in the Selenium code, and why do you believe that?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Are you developing an extension module for the Spring community? If not, why is your module named group id `org.springframework` and artifact id `gs-spring-boot`?

Comment: You have a dozens of errors! The above is a good first catch. No selenium in your deps. But you also have mechanical import problems.  Do yourself a favor and either start building an app small, get it working, then add on, or copy some nice boilerplate from the interwebs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `pom.xml` is all messed up.

I will try to add sample jars based on your usage as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Pls change `groupId` `artifactId`
as per your project package

Also I notice your `CarTest` class has package `cars` so I guess your project package is also messed up.

In that case, I would suggest trying to build a project from [here](https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me solve an issue on eclipse.  I have the same application (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) running in windows eclipse and on ubuntu (I run using mvn command line tool). It ran without any issue on Ubuntu, on eclipse on windows it did not run till I added the spring-boot-starter-test and hamcrest-all dependencies you mention above. WHat could be the reason that it works in one env and not in the other